# Cache efficient heap for heap sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am working on project where I want to sort data using heap sort because worst case is very important for my project. I  Know that quick sort is more fast on avg case but I can't use it in my project because of o(n^2) worst case.

I want to know is there any cache efficient heap which I can use for heap sort which has less space complexity?  And I want to know  The effect of cache efficiency on heap sort and quick sort?  And how much it affect heap sort?  Is it affect is too much or negligible?

Comment: I would suggest [Introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort). It attempts a Quicksort, but will fall back to Heap sort if the recursion gets too deep. Check your language library's sort implementation: it might already be using a hybrid algorithm such as Introsort or TimSort.

Answer (score 2):

[Funnel heaps](http://www.cs.au.dk/~gerth/papers/alcomft-tr-02-136.pdf) are a cache-oblivious alternative to plain old heaps. I don't know how much, if any, they help, I've never benchmarked them.

4-ary heaps, which are a form of [d-ary heaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-ary_heap), are not cache-oblivious or even tuned to any specific cache size, but work out a little better than 2-ary (ie binary) heaps anyway because they're shallower. That effect does not keep working if you keep increasing `d`, 4 or 8 are great, but for higher `d` the per-level overhead takes over and becomes more significant than the savings from having fewer levels.

The space complexity of heap sort isn't really improvable, since it's already O(1) assuming you use the standard technique of heapifying the input in-place and then putting the result there too.

As for the good old heapsort vs quicksort, here's a [different take on it](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/sort.html), with an [interesting response](http://users.aims.ac.za/~mackay/sorting/sorting.html). TL;DR: don't just repeat the old "quicksort beats heapsort", it's more complicated.

Comment: Interesting. The testing I've done on my machine with heaps up to 2^20 nodes, indicates that a 3-heap or a 4-heap will almost always outperform a 2-heap. A 5-heap will *sometimes* outperform a 2-heap. Nothing higher does. The difference between 3-heap and 4-heap is typically very small.